# Javascript function won't take input, "Uncaught ReferenceError: p is not defined"

Tags: javascript, math

Problem's occuring when testing in Chrome, but I'm sure it'll happen in any browser.

Why am I getting the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: p is not defined"? I'm just trying to pass some numbers and directives through, eg. doControllerConversion(p,tr,300); but instead it errors out. Is it because I'm not using strings? I'm at my wits end here...

Thanks so much. I'm a total noob.

```
function doControllerConversion(s1, o1, u1) {

    var selector;
    var orientation;
    var userInput;
    s1 = selector;
    o1 = orientation;
    u1 = userInput;

    if (UserSettings.controllerType == "KH606") {
        if (selector == 'p') {
            if (orientation == "toRtraw") {
                return userInput * 2.85;
            } else if (orientation == 'fr') {
                return userInput / 2.85;
            }
        } else if (selector == 'b') {
            if (orientation == "tr") {
                return userInput * 5.10;
            } else if (orientation == 'fr') {
                return userInput / 5.10;
            }
        } else {
            return errorOut(1);
        }
    }

    if (UserSettings.controllerType == "KH609") {
        if (selector == 'p') {
            if (orientation == 'tr') {
                return userInput * 2.46;
            } else if (orientation == 'fr') {
                return userInput / 2.46;
            }
        } else if (selector == 'b') {
            if (orientation == 'tr') {
                return userInput * 5.10;
            } else if (orientation == 'fr') {
                return userInput / 5.10;
            }
        } else {
            return errorOut(1);
        }
    }

    if (UserSettings.controllerType == "KH612") {
        if (selector == 'p') {
            if (orientation == 'tr') {
                return userInput * 1.20;
            } else if (orientation == 'fr') {
                return userInput / 1.20;
            }
        } else if (selector == 'b') {
            if (orientation == 'tr') {
                return userInput * 2.73;
            } else if (orientation == 'fr') {
                return userInput / 2.73;
            }
        }
    }

    if (UserSettings.controllerType == "KH615") {
        if (selector == 'p') {
            if (orientation == 'tr') {
                return userInput * 0.79;
            } else if (orientation == 'fr') {
                return userInput / 0.79;
            }
        } else if (selector == 'b') {
            if (orientation == 'tr') {
                return userInput * 2.55;
            } else if (orientation == 'fr') {
                return userInput / 2.55;
            }
        }
    }

    if (UserSettings.controllerType == "KH618") {
        if (selector == 'p') {
            if (orientation == 'tr') {
                return userInput * 0.53;
            } else if (orientation == 'fr') {
                return userInput / 0.53;
            }
        } else if (selector == 'b') {
            if (orientation == 'tr') {
                return userInput * 1.70;
            } else if (orientation == 'fr') {
                return userInput / 1.70;
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Error on basic conversion!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have defined the p variable that you are passing into the function? doControllerConversion(p,tr,300);

Comment: looks like you haven't defined p in the scope where you are calling your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the parameters your sending,check whether your passing string values to the function,
sending it as:

```
doControllerConversion('p','tr',300)
```

seems to be working

Comment: is this lines also works: s1 = selector; i think i will be selector=s1

Comment: I think this is the answer! I feel like such a dope! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

in strict mode you must to define all variables,  functions, etc.